# Need help in verifying chain condition for applying Zorn's Lemma

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory, modules

While self studying abstract algebra from thomas hungerford I have following question in proof of Lemma $6.8$ (Page $222$)

> **Lemma** $6.8.$ Let $A$ be a module over a principal ideal domain $R$ such that $p^{n}A = 0$ and $p^{n-1}A \neq 0$ for some prime $p\in R$ and positive  integer $n$. Let $a$ be an element of $A$ of order $p^n$.
> $(i)$ If $A\neq Ra$, then there exists a nonzero $b\in A$ such that $Ra \cap Rb = 0$.
> $(ii)$ There is a submodule $C$ of $A$ such that $A = Ra\oplus C$.

Question is in part $2$ of proof $(ii)$

> In Case $A\neq Ra$ author defines as $S$ as the set of all submodules $B$ of $A$ such that $Ra\cap B =0$. It is easily proved to be non-empty. Then it is partially ordered by set theoretic inclusion and author says to verify that every chain in $S$ has an upper bound in $S$.

How can I verify that every chain in $S$ has an upper bound in $S$? What upper bound should I take?

I am really confused.

Kindly shed some light on how one should verify upper bound in this sort of questions.

Comment: The first upper bound to try when the order is inclusion is the union. If you can show that the union of a chain of submodules with that property is a submodule with that property, you’re good to go.

Comment: To add on @spaceisdarkgreen, if union is not the answer, then "object generated by the union" is almost always the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider $S=\{B\leqslant A\,\mid\,Ra\cap B=0\}$. Let $B_0\subseteq B_1\subseteq B_2\subseteq\dots$ be a chain in $S$. Let $B=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}B_n$. Note that this is the usual first try when dealing with an elementary application of Zorn's Lemma (as already noted by *spaceisdarkgreen* in the comments).

As any actual calculation in $B$ can already be carried out in some particular $B_{n_0}$ (since the $B_n$ form a chain) for some $n_0\in\Bbb N$, $B_{n_0}$ being a submodule of $A$, we conclude that $B$ is a submodule of $A$ aswell (you might want to make this argument more precise). Now, suppose $Ra\cap B\ne0$ and let $x\in Ra\cap B$ where $x\ne0$. By definition there is some $n_0\in\Bbb N$ such that $x\in B_{n_0}$. But then $Ra\cap B_{n_0}\ne0$ contrary to our assumption. Thus $Ra\cap B=0$ and you can continue by applying Zorn's Lemma as $B$ is an upper bound for the given arbitrary chain.

This sketch is applicable in a lot (not all) similar cases: consider the union of the whole chain and show that this construction yields an upper bound with the same structure.